# How programmatically extract type description which is shown by intellisense as hint

Tags: c#, xml-documentation

When I type some Class, e.g. Console, then press ctrl+space and intellisense show hint "Class System.Console Represents standart input, output and error streams...."
How programmatically get this text. Can't find in google, may be I'm stupid noob.
Thanks.

Comment: In what type of application do you want to retrieve this text? Web, Windows, Console, ...?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. This is a documentation string parsed by IntelliSense and does not exist in the exe or dll file at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse .xml file with documentation if you know where it's located.

EDIT: If you'd like to get documentation from .NET classes, you can see folders in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework` and find there files .xml with xml-documentation.

Comment: I need this functional on developer machine where VS and MSDN installed. So i nedd some ideas how intellisense do it and do it myself.

Comment: VS takes .xml file with documentation, parses it, and shows you hint. Documentation for class Console you can find in file mscorlib.xml. (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\\)

Answer (score 0):

You get some of that info through Reflection. Like MethodInfo that shows the information about a method.

Comment: I think you won't find documentation in MethodInfo.